# Plot elements in a column of a dataframe on the same graph sharing the same x-axis in datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, plot, x-axis

I have a dataframe:

```
    Element Date                Q

0   A       24/10/2021 17:16    400
1   B       24/10/2021 18:59    210
2   A       26/10/2021 18:42    325
3   A       26/10/2021 19:44    589
4   B       29/10/2021 14:23    251
5   A       01/11/2021 9:12     578
6   B       02/11/2021 21:30    321
7   A       04/11/2021 18:25    248
8   B       05/11/2021 10:29    854
9   A       05/11/2021 10:26    968
10  A       07/11/2021 18:10    852
11  A       09/11/2021 16:35    425
12  B       09/11/2021 21:55    752
13  A       11/11/2021 18:41    385
14  B       13/11/2021 11:15    658
15  A       14/11/2021 18:17    229
16  B       16/11/2021 22:36    258
17  A       17/11/2021 17:05    359
18  A       18/11/2021 16:39    210
19  B       19/11/2021 15:41    583
```

and I want to plot value "Q" of two elements in column "Element" in the same graph sharing the same x-axis, but I can't get it.

I have tried to separate them in two dataframes, but it is not a good solution:

```
    Element Date                Q
0   A       24/10/2021 17:16    400
2   A       26/10/2021 18:42    325
3   A       26/10/2021 19:44    589
5   A       01/11/2021 9:12     578
7   A       04/11/2021 18:25    248
9   A       05/11/2021 10:26    968
10  A       07/11/2021 18:10    852
11  A       09/11/2021 16:35    425
13  A       11/11/2021 18:41    385
15  A       14/11/2021 18:17    229
17  A       17/11/2021 17:05    359
18  A       18/11/2021 16:39    210
```

```
    Element Date                Q
1   B       24/10/2021 18:59    210
4   B       29/10/2021 14:23    251
6   B       02/11/2021 21:30    321
8   B       05/11/2021 10:29    854
12  B       09/11/2021 21:55    752
14  B       13/11/2021 11:15    658
16  B       16/11/2021 22:36    258
19  B       19/11/2021 15:41    583
```

This is the result of two attempts:

```
ax = dfA.plot.scatter(x="Date",y="Q",rot=90)
dfB.plot.scatter(x="Date",y="Q",rot=90, ax=ax, color='r')
```

[Graph 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKa6U.png)

```
df_A = df[df['Element'] == 'A'].set_index('Date')
df_B = df[df['Element'] == 'B'].set_index('Date')

plt.figure()

ax = df_A[['Q']].plot(figsize=(20,5))
df_B[['Q']].plot(ax=ax)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[Graph 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbKla.png)

I want to represent the two sets of points sharing the x-axis with a common date range and I need a legend with the labels "A" and "B".

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt would have worked had you converted the `Date` columns to Timestamp. A scatter plot requires that values on x- and y-axis to be numerical. When you supply strings on the x-axis, they are treated as positions [0, 1, 2, 3,...] with *tick marks* equal to the supplied values.

```py
for df in [dfA, dfB]:
    df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], dayfirst=True)

ax = dfA.plot.scatter(x="Date", y="Q", rot=90, label="A")
dfB.plot.scatter(x="Date", y="Q", rot=90, ax=ax, color="r", label="B")
```

[image]